# how to remove entries from map based on its value presence in a given list?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have a list of Strings:

```
List<String> countries;
```

it contains countries, e.g.:

```
Austria, Poland, England
```

and I have a map:

```
Map<String, String> data;
```

This map contains entries such as:

```
one   | Austria
two   | Germany
three | France
```

etc.

How can I filter the map so that at the end it has only the entries that are not in the list? For the example given above, the output map would contain:

```
two   | Germany
three | France
```

I tried using java8 filters, but with no positive result, could you help me with that?

Comment: What do you think, your approach should be?

Comment: Change `keySet` to `values` in the linked duplicate. The principle is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with **Java8+** you can use :

```
data.values().removeIf(s -> countries.contains(s));
```

display the result you can use :

```
data.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.println(k + " | " + v));
```

Outputs

```
two | Germany
three | France
```

Comment: thank you, that looks great, one last question - is there any way in java8 to also do the other way around, e.g. to leave in map only the records that are present in the list?

Comment: Yes of course you can just put **!** the not anchor before the condition like `data.values().removeIf(s -> !countries.contains(s));` :)

Comment: But this has no advantage over the old `data.values().removeAll(countries);` or `data.values().retainAll(countries);`. The new `removeIf` operation is a great tool for more complex conditions, but you should not overuse it.